# Display Values Of Variable At Each Step Of Execution

Tags: python, debugging, variables

Which debugger should I use to display the value of variables at each call/step. I have the following sample code:

```
def sample_func1(a, b):
    c = a + b
    print(c)
    a = 10 + b
    b = 20 - a
    print(a, b)
def sample_func2(x, y):
    z = x - y
    print(z)

p = 10
q = 20
d = sample_func1(p, q)
w = sample_func2(p, q)
```

I am using jupyter notebook.

Comment: Your question is not related to your code, it is a question "Which debugger should I use?" in disguise.  [And this question is off topic for SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I had already mentioned at the beginning that it is a sample code. I have modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

Other than printing out (a, b, c) and (x, y) at every iteration, the best way to see each variable and step through the code is to use a different text editor. Visual Studio is great for this, but if you like Jupyter's interface, you can use Rodeo (https://www.yhat.com/products/rodeo) which is similar and optimized for data science.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Spyder which is an opensource and found the option that I was looking for.